# How to send http request on button click with inertia react?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, inertiajs

How can I immediately send a request using the provided code when the `"+"` button is clicked, and ensure that the request is sent to `"/cashier/cart/add"` with the updated data (`cart_id` and `quantity`)?

```
const { data: addData, setData: setAddData, post: postAdd } = useForm({
    cart_id: "",
    quantity: "",
});
```

```
<Button
    size={"icon2"}
    disabled={
        item?.product?.stock <=
        0
    }
    onClick={(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const updatedData = {
            ...addData,
            cart_id: item.id,
            quantity: 1,
        };
        postAdd(
            "/cashier/cart/add",
            {
                data: updatedData,
                preserveScroll: true,
                preserveState: true,
            }
        );
    }}
>
    +
</Button>
```

How can I immediately send a request using the provided code when the `"+"` button is clicked, and ensure that the request is sent to `"/cashier/cart/add"` with the updated data (`cart_id` and `quantity`)?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're using a custom hook called useForm and a Button component. To ensure that the request is sent immediately when the "+" button is clicked, you should make sure that the postAdd function triggers the HTTP request. Here's an updated version of your code to achieve this:

```
import React from 'react';

// Assuming you have useForm and Button components

const YourComponent = () => {
    const { data: addData, setData: setAddData, post: postAdd } = useForm({
        cart_id: "",
        quantity: "",
    });

    const handleAddButtonClick = async () => {
        const updatedData = {
            ...addData,
            cart_id: item.id,
            quantity: 1,
        };

        try {
            // Assuming postAdd returns a promise
            await postAdd("/cashier/cart/add", {
                data: updatedData,
                preserveScroll: true,
                preserveState: true,
            });

            // Handle success or any additional logic after the request is sent
            console.log('Request sent successfully!');
        } catch (error) {
            // Handle errors, if any
            console.error('Error sending request:', error);
        }
    };

    return (
        <Button
            size={"icon2"}
            disabled={item?.product?.stock <= 0}
            onClick={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                handleAddButtonClick();
            }}
        >
            +
        </Button>
    );
};

export default YourComponent;
```

This code uses an asynchronous function handleAddButtonClick to wait for the postAdd function to complete the request. This ensures that the request is sent immediately when the "+" button is clicked. Additionally, error handling is included to catch any potential errors during the request. Adjust the code as needed based on your specific implementation of postAdd and error handling requirements.